# Problemas com iframe no Firefox e Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Estou com um problema no Firefox e no Internet Explorer ao utilizar uma `iframe` para carregar arquivos na mesma pagina.

No Chrome funciona perfeitamente, mas no Firefox e no Internet Explorer, quando clico no `link` o `iframe` abre em outra página.

Alguém tem alguma solução ou alternativa?

O exemplo do código em baixo pode ser visto no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scofieldm1/J3E8n/) ou nesta [pagina de experimentos](http://se.mediagruppe.com/SE/MG/EXTRANET/experiments/exemplo-iframe/index.php).

```
<li><a href="pagina-1.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 1</a></li>
<li><a href="pagina-2.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 2</a></li>
<li><a href="pagina-3.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 3</a></li>  
<li><a href="pagina-4.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 4</a></li>
<li><a href="pagina-5.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 5</a></li>
<li><a href="pagina-6.htm" target="plantas" class="">pagina 6</a></li>

<iframe id="plantas" height="500"  width="887" src="pagina-1.htm"
 frameborder="0"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua iFrame é o `name` que deve ser usado, nao o `id`

Tente assim, usando `name="plantas"`:

```
<iframe id="plantas" name="plantas" height="500"  width="887" src="pagina-1.htm" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/J3E8n/1/)

Segundo a [**documentação da MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

> **name**
>   A name for the embedded browsing context (or frame). This can be used as the value of the target attribute of an `<a>` or `<form>` element, or the formtarget attribute of an `<input>` or `<button>` element.

Em Português:

> **name**
>   O nome para o contexto da frame. Isto pode ser usado como valor do atributo target de um elemento `<a>` ou `<form>`, ou o atributo formtarget de um elemento `<input>` ou `<button>`.

Comment: imaginei que seria algo mais complexo, ja estava migrando para o ajax, mas como é um projeto de curto prazo teve que ser iframe mesmo, de qualquer forma, obrigado @sergio.